# How to change the font in the grid GXT3

Tags: java, gxt

Sorry for the simple question, how to change the font in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the text which might be displayed in one of your columns, you can do this easily with cells. When you set up your `ColumnModel` class, you can pass a custom cell to one of the columns. Then, with html and css, you can style up the column per your needs.

If you want to change the column headers, then you can simply pass some SafeHtml to that column's `ColumnConfig.setHeader(SafeHtml)` method. Again, this would be done when you set up your `ColumnModel`. This let's you style up the header however you wish.

If you do use images or css, I highly suggest using the `ClientBundle` and `CSSResource` classes.